# Using html5 appcache with media queries for pixel ratio

Tags: css, media-queries, html5-appcache, pixel-density

I have a web app which uses [media queries based on pixel ratio](http://cssforge.com/tutorials/designing-for-retina-css-media-queries-and-background-size/) to deliver images of an appropriate resolution to client devices. For example, it will deliver 1x images to a Windows desktop and 2x images to an iPhone with retina display.

I am interested in using the [HTML5 application cache feature](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) to enable my web app to be used offline. To do this you must create a manifest file that lists all the files needed by your app. When a user visits the app, the browser gets the manifest and downloads all the files listed in it, in preparation for going offline.

It sounds to me like this will negate the point of my media queries, as I will have to put both 1x and 2x images in the manifest, and all clients will end up downloading all images.

The main solution that comes to mind is to dynamically deliver the manifest, using user agent sniffing to decide whether the manifest should include 1x or 2x images. This is feasible for me but I am curious what other solutions are out there for dealing with this issue, or is it just a known limitation/quirk?

Comment: Which devices are you planning to allow the app to be used offline with?

Comment: The main platforms I'm concerned about are Windows, Mac, Linux desktops, plus iOS, Android and Windows Phone devices.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that you may be able to use media queries to selectively download only the images that are needed for each particular device.  Results have shown in the past that [media queries will only attempt to download images that are needed](http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/), if it's reasonable to assume that some images are not needed. Test Seven at the bottom of that page seems to be quite relevant to your question.

You could create a CSS file with the pixel ratio media queries and list it in your manifest file and then check on the device to see whether or not it actually downloaded unnecessary image resources.

Comment: Thanks for your response! You're right, and this is how the web app behaves today. But the problem is that I believe that the manifest file needs to list not just my CSS file but also all of the images (1x and 2x) that the CSS references. The manifest file doesn't distinguish between 1x and 2x and so the browser will download all of them, negating the selective download that you mention.

I must admit that this is speculation though, based on reading how the offline/appcache feature works. I will try to knock up a simple test page to prove that the issue exists.

Answer (score 0):

Tackled the same requirement myself, I've created an express middleware just for this, intended to work with or without AppCache and/or Cordova, supporting the prefix-dpi-suffix (e.g file@2x.jpg) syntax.

You can use it with content images, css files containing media queries, or any other file actually, just add @[num]x to your files and it will serve that instead of the "normal" file (you can use your own prefix and suffix strings).

This means that when a browser requests a file named mypic.png on a device with device pixel ratio of 2, the middleware will actually try to serve mypic@2x.png first, and only if it doesn't exist, it will serve mypic.png.

[static-denser](https://github.com/aabluedragon/static-denser)

[static-denser-demo](https://github.com/aabluedragon/static-denser-demo)

---

### Update

A more elegant solution can be achieved using [Service Workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers), not supported by all browsers at this time.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers